# How to determine if a solution to a 2nd order ODE is oscillatory or not without solving it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

So suppose I have the a standard homogeneous second order ODE

$y'' +P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0$

and I'm told to determine if its nonzero solutions are oscillatory or not (meaning have infinitely many roots).

My attempt at the solution is:

First reformulate the DE into normal form

$u'' + J(x)u = 0$

where $J(x) = Q(x) - \frac{1}{4}P(x)^2 - \frac{1}{2}P'(x)$ assuming $P(x) \in C^1$

and from there I would get

$J(x) = -\frac{u''}{u}$

and if $J(x)$ goes to zero at different points (infinitely many usually) then $u''$ is going to zero and this implies that also $u'$ would have to change signs at some point and that implies $u$ becomes zero and so the solution is oscillatory, however if $J(x)$ does not go to zero ever then the solution is not oscilatory.

Is this the right way to go about this problem?

Comment: If $J(x)$ has a positive lower bound, you can apply the Storm-Picone comparison theorem, which then provides for infinitely many roots.